# Temporary wrap array items with same type inside an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, algorithm, object

This is a part of content received from a json api

```
contents: [
 { title: "some title", content_type: 2 },
 { title: "some title", content_type: 2 },
 { title: "some title", content_type: 1 },
 { title: "some title", content_type: 2 },
 { title: "some title", content_type: 1 },
]
```

For me to perform operations on this data it would me much easier to wrap items with same type that follow one another into a separate array, for example:

```
contents: [
 type2: [
   { title: "some title", content_type: 2 },
   { title: "some title", content_type: 2 }
 ],
 { title: "some title", content_type: 1 },
 { title: "some title", content_type: 2 },
 { title: "some title", content_type: 1 },
]
```

Note there is another content with type 2, but as it is a single one, no need to wrap it in a temporary array. I need to figure out a way to do this efficiently and be able to remove this wrapper quickly when I need to post to the server.

Comment: the result look invalid. contents is either an object, the the type1 are wrong or an array, the type1 is wrong. inside of type1 is an array ...?

Comment: @NinaScholz my mistake, corrected

Comment: you need the type2 in a separate property in an *array*?

Comment: @NinaScholz type2 is just a name referring to content_type on items it nests, it can be named anything.

Comment: I think you need to provide a bit more detail about what you need to accomplish and why. As Nina pointed out, your desired outcome is not even a valid data structure in JavaScript. What processing do you want to perform that requires the change in structure?

Answer (score 0):

```
var contents= [
 { title: "some title", content_type: 2 },
 { title: "some title", content_type: 2 },
 { title: "some title", content_type: 1 },
 { title: "some title", content_type: 2 },
 { title: "some title", content_type: 1 },
];

var wrap = function(contents) {
    var obj = {};
    contents.forEach(function(row) {
        var key = 'type' + row.content_type;
        if (!obj[key]) {
            obj[key] = [];
        }

        obj[key].push(row);
    });
    return obj;
};

var contents2 = wrap(contents);

console.log(contents2);

var unwrap = function(contents) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i in contents) {
        arr = arr.concat(contents[i]);
    }
    return arr;
};

var contents3 = unwrap(contents2);

console.log(contents3);
```

Which gives you:

```
{ type2: 
   [ { title: 'some title', content_type: 2 },
     { title: 'some title', content_type: 2 },
     { title: 'some title', content_type: 2 } ],
  type1: 
   [ { title: 'some title', content_type: 1 },
     { title: 'some title', content_type: 1 } ] }


[ { title: 'some title', content_type: 2 },
  { title: 'some title', content_type: 2 },
  { title: 'some title', content_type: 2 },
  { title: 'some title', content_type: 1 },
  { title: 'some title', content_type: 1 } ]
```

Comment: issue here is that I want to wrap first 2 items, leave 1 unwrapped, leave 2 unwrapped etc.. so in a nut shel only same types that follow one another in the array need to be wrapped